# Laravel Display Array on blade with "unserialize"

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

im facing an issue to retrive an array from my database and display it on my blade.

So to understand my work, im actualy saving "**Cart**" informations on my "**Orders Table**" with Serialize the **Products**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $order = new Order();
        $order->user_id = request('user_id');
        $order->wilaya = request('wilaya');
        $order->province = request('province');
        $order->address = request('address');
        $order->phone = request('phone');
        $order->quantity = request('quantity');
        $order->subtotal = request('total');
        $order->status = request('status');

        $products = [];
        $i = 0;

        foreach (Cart::content() as $product){
            $products['product_' . $i][]= $product->name;
            $products['product_' . $i][]= $product->options->color;
            $products['product_' . $i][]= $product->price;
            $products['product_' . $i][]= $product->options->size;
            $products['product_' . $i][]= $product->options->image;
            $products['product_' . $i][]= $product->qty;
            $i++;
        }


        $order->products = serialize($products);
        //dd($order);
        if(Cart::count() <= 0){
            return redirect('/products');
        }else{
        $order->save();
        Cart::destroy();
        return view('checkout.thankyou');
        }

    }
```

So when i try to retrive my data from the **"Products"** column with **Unserialize** on my show ressource

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $orderShow = Order::find($id);
        $arr = unserialize($orderShow->products);
        dd($arr);
        return view('dashboard.order.show', compact('orderShow', 'arr'));
    }
```

I get this result

```
array:2 [▼
  "product_0" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "T-Shirt Fashion 3"
    1 => "black"
    2 => 1300.0
    3 => "S"
    4 => "QFh840we7wZBKO790A6wFlipJB1ASaCpt3zJhJl8.png"
    5 => 1
  ]
  "product_1" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "T-Shirt Fashion"
    1 => "green"
    2 => 1200.0
    3 => "L"
    4 => "CdMVwEJcMQbJjMp70UhRnkNQnRmWxzAGiWKxFeWN.png"
    5 => 1
  ]
]
```

[result of dd($arr) with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azekj.png)

I also try this

```
$json = json_encode(unserialize($orderShow->products));
```

And i get this result

```
"{"product_0":["T-Shirt Fashion 3","black",1300,"S","QFh840we7wZBKO790A6wFlipJB1ASaCpt3zJhJl8.png",1],"product_1":["T-Shirt Fashion","green",1200,"L","CdMVwEJcMQbJjMp70UhRnkNQnRmWxzAGiWKxFeWN.png",1]} ◀"
```

So i dont know how to deal with these arrays on my blade, i know that i need a Foreach loop to display it on the right way, but i have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a good idea to store your `$products` as an object (with key and value) instead of a pure array.

In your `store` function, you can try the following :

```php
$products = [];
foreach (Cart::content() as $product) {
    // similar to array_push()
    $products[] = [
        "name" => $product->name,
        "color" => $product->options->color,
        "price" => $product->price,
        "size" => $product->options->size,
        "image" => $product->options->image,
        "qty" => $product->qty,
     ];
}
```

In your `show` function

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $orderShow = Order::find($id);
    $products = unserialize($orderShow->products);
    return view('dashboard.order.show', compact('orderShow', 'products'));
}
```

Then, in your blade template, if you need to display `$products` as a table:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>color</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>size</th>
            <th>image</th>
            <th>qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$product['name']}}</td>
            <td>{{$product['color']}}</td>
            <td>{{$product['price']}}</td>
            <td>{{$product['size']}}</td>
            <td>{{$product['image']}}</td>
            <td>{{$product['qty']}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Quick tip, it is a good practice to define attributes (de)serialization in your model instead of your controller.
Have a look at [Eloquent Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator), and update your `Order.php` model with the following :

```php
class Order extends Model {
  // ...

  public function setProductsAttribute($products)
  {
    $this->attributes['products'] = serialize($products);
  }

  public function getProductsAttribute()
  {
    return unserialize($this->attributes['products']);
  }

  // ...
}
```